# SQL Developer setting for Feedback

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to set the option `set feedback on` or `set feedback off` permanently in Oracle SQL Developer?

Answer (score 1):

A method of controlling options such as this is in SQL Developer is to use a connection start-up script. This option is available in Tools > Preferences > Database - then select the script you wish to run for connection start up (in this case the script would contain `set feedback on;` or `set feedback off;`). Each time you create a connection or open a new Unshared SQL Worksheet this script will be run.